# Swift: Passing a parameter to selector

Tags: ios, swift3

Using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1

Method:

```
func moveToNextTextField(tag: Int) {
   print(tag)
}
```

The lines below compile fine, but `tag` has an uninitialized value:

```
let selector = #selector(moveToNextTextField)
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

However, I need to pass a parameter.  Below fails to compile:

```
let selector = #selector(moveToNextTextField(tag: 2))

Swift Compile Error:
Argument of #selector does not refer to an @objc method, property, or initializer.
```

How can I pass an argument to a selector?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`#selector` describes method signature only. In your case the correct way to initialize the selector is

```
let selector = #selector(moveToNextTextField(tag:))
```

Timer has the common target-action mechanism. Target is usually self and action is a method that takes one parameter `sender: Timer`. You should save additional data to `userInfo` dictionary, and extract it from `sender` parameter in the method:

```
func moveToNextTextField(sender: Timer) {
   print(sender.userInfo?["tag"])
}
...
let selector = #selector(moveToNextTextField(sender:))
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: selector, userInfo: ["tag": 2], repeats: false)
```

Comment: vadian is correct. You can't pass a custom parameter through a timer. You have to install the parameter into the timer's userInfo field. (The selector can either pass in the timer as a parameter, or no parameters.)

Comment: Printing sender.userInfo as shown in your answer gives me the error "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts"

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass a custom parameter through a `Timer` action.

Either

```
#selector(moveToNextTextField)
...
func moveToNextTextField()
```

or

```
#selector(moveToNextTextField(_:))
...
func moveToNextTextField(_ timer : Timer)
```

is supported, nothing else.

To pass custom parameters use the `userInfo` dictionary.