# Function with a CGFloat as a parameter

Tags: swift3

I am trying to make this function work with a progress bar:

```
var progressTimer: Timer?
var time: CGFloat = 0

func setProgress(duration: CGFloat) {
    time += 0.1
    progressFront.progress = time / duration
    if time >= duration {
        progressTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}

func updateProgress() {
    progressTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.setProgress)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func pauseUpdateProgress() {
    progressTimer?.invalidate()
}
```

Calling the function like this and it just does't work:

```
setProgress(duration: 20)
```

While if i hardcode it like follows, it works just fine:

```
func setProgress() {

            time += 0.1
            progressFront.progress = time / 20

            if time >= 20 {
                progressTimer?.invalidate()
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show all class code ?

Comment: Maybe not related but avoid function names starting with `set`. They might interfere with property setters. And if you are using the function as a timer selector, that does not work indeed because you can only pass the timer instance as parameter.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for your advice and comment. I seem to be inappropriately using the function as a timer selector (updated the code). What can I do to make this function reusable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Passing a parameter to selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987324/swift-passing-a-parameter-to-selector)

Comment: PS: How / where do you pass the value (20) practically using your syntax ... ? Read the linked topic and use the `userInfo` dictionary to pass parameters.

Comment: @AntonPlatonov your code works fine in playground. Whats the message you are getting from compiler? You said " it just does't work" means what exactly is happening?

Comment: It compiles just fine. It does't take the parameter other than that from the type 'Timer'. See answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you have a parameter to the `Timer` handler, it must be the `Timer` itself:

```
func setProgress(_ timer: Timer) {
    ...
}
```

Second, the `#selector` should indicate what the parameters are to the method, e.g. `#selector(setProgress(_:))`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but how will I be able to call setProgress() with various parameters if I hardcode something in the #selector. I want to use this function for multiple progress bars. I am new to programming so I am utterly confused. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: When you use `Timer`, you don't control what the parameter of the selector is. It's always going to be the `Timer`, itself. If you want to pass information to the selector, you (a) supply a dictionary to `userInfo` parameter of `scheduledTimer`; and (b) `setProgress` can then retrieve this `userInfo`. Or, easier, use the block-based [`scheduledTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer).

Answer (score 0):

The `selector` for a `Timer` can have one parameter but that parameter must be of type `Timer`. You just cannot pass duration this way.

However, that's exactly why there is a `userInfo` parameter and you can pass:

```
... userInfo: ["duration": 20.0], repeats: true)
```

Even that probably isn't the best solution for you because after pausing, you will have to pass the duration again.

The simplest solution is to save the duration into a property.

```
var duration: CGFloat = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please expand on how I can use this simple solution in may particular case. I need to call this function many times.